# Verifying that the determinant is equal to $1!2!3!...(n-1)!$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Verifying that the determinant is equal to $1!2!3!...(n-1)!$

$$|A|=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 &1 & \dots &1\\
1 &2 & \dots &2^{n-1}\\
1 &3 & \dots &3^{n-1}\\
& & \dots\\
1 &n & \dots &n^{n-1}\\
\end{vmatrix}=1!2!3!...(n-1)!
$$

I used the definition of a determinan with Minors and Cofactors, ie.

$$|A|=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}i^{j-1}\cdot A_{ij}=i^{1-1=0}\cdot A_{i 1}+i^{2-1=1}\cdot A_{i 2}+i^{3-1=2}\cdot A_{i 3}+\dots+i^{n-1}\cdot A_{i n-1}$$

So, what we want to prove is equal to:

$$|A|=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}i^{j-1}\cdot A_{ij}=1!2!3! \dots (n-1)!$$

Proving for $n=1$

$$|A|=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}i^{j-1}\cdot A_{ij}=|1|=0!=1$$

INDUCTIVE H:

Asume

$$|A|=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}i^{j-1}\cdot A_{ij}=i^{0}\cdot A_{i 1}+i^{1}\cdot A_{i 2}+i^{2}\cdot A_{i 3}+\dots+i^{n-1}\cdot A_{i n-1}=1!2!3!...(n-1)$$

So, for $n+1$ we have:

$$|A|=\sum_{j=1}^{n}i^{j-1}\cdot A_{ij}=i^{0}\cdot A_{i 1}+i^{1}\cdot A_{i 2}+i^{2}\cdot A_{i 3}+\dots+i^{n-1}\cdot A_{i n-1}+i^{n}\cdot A_{i n}$$

INDUCTIVE STEP:

$$|A|=\sum_{j=1}^{n}i^{j-1}\cdot A_{ij}=(1!2!3! \dots (n-1)!)+i^{n}\cdot A_{i n}$$

AND AT THIS POINT, I DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO.

Comment: A bunch of your sums go from $1$ to $n-1$ when they should be from $1$ to $n$ I think.  And the last two sums should be from $1$ to $n+1$.

Comment: Your proof idea has an error also.  You seem to be assuming the cofactors $A_{ij}$ are the same for the $n$ case and the $n+1$ case.

Comment: i asume they are, because in the case $n+1$ we add one row and column to the $n$ case

Comment: Otherwise, which proof idea could i use?

Comment: Adding one row and column does not change the previous entries, but it *does* change the cofactors.  In particular,
\begin{align*}
\text{Cofactors}
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\ 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
&= \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1\\ -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
\text{Cofactors}
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 4 \\ 1 & 3 & 9
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
&= \begin{bmatrix}
6 & -5 & 1 \\ -6 & 8 & -2 \\ 2 & -3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
I'm writing up an answer, give me a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can evaluate this determinant as follows.
Let $A_n$ be the $n \times n$ matrix in question.
First, for each $j = n-1, n-2, \ldots, 1$, subtract $n$ times column $j$ from column $j+1$.
This results in the following:
\begin{align*}
|A_n| &=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1-n & 1-n & \ldots & 1-n & \ldots & 1-n \\
1 & 2 - n & 2^2 - 2n & \ldots & 2^{j-1} - 2^{j-2}n & \ldots & 2^{n-1} - 2^{n-2}n \\
1 & 3 - n & 3^2 - 3n & \ldots & 3^{j-1} - 3^{j-2}n & \ldots & 3^{n-1} - 3^{n-2}n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & i - n & i^2 - in & \ldots & i^{j-1} - i^{j-2}n & \ldots & i^{n-1} - i^{n-2}n \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & n - n & n^2 - n^2 & \ldots & n^{j-1} - n^{j-1} & \ldots & n^{n-1} - n^{n-1} \end{vmatrix} \\
&\; \\ &\; \\&\; \\ &\; \\ %vertical space
&=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1-n & 1-n & \ldots & 1-n & \ldots & 1-n \\
1 & 2 - n & 2(2-n) & \ldots & 2^{j-2}(2-n) & \ldots & 2^{n-2}(2-n) \\
1 & 2 - n & 3(3-n) & \ldots & 3^{j-2}(3-n) & \ldots & 3^{n-2}(3-n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & i - n & i(i-n) & \ldots & i^{j-2}(i-n) & \ldots & i^{n-2}(i-n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & (-1)  & (n-1)(-1) & \ldots & (n-1)^{j-2}(-1) & \ldots & (n-1)^{n-2}(-1) \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
\end{vmatrix}
\end{align*}
By cofactor expansion along the bottom row,
\begin{align*}
&= (-1)^{n+1}
\begin{vmatrix}
1-n & 1-n & \ldots & 1-n & \ldots & 1-n \\
2 - n & 2(2-n) & \ldots & 2^{j-1}(2-n) & \ldots & 2^{n-2}(2-n) \\
2 - n & 3(3-n) & \ldots & 3^{j-1}(3-n) & \ldots & 3^{n-2}(3-n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
i - n & i(i-n) & \ldots & i^{j-1}(i-n) & \ldots & i^{n-2}(i-n) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(-1)  & (n-1)(-1) & \ldots & (n-1)^{j-1}(-1) & \ldots & (n-1)^{n-2}(-1) \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
&\; \\ &\; \\&\; \\ &\; \\ %vertical space
&= (-1)^{n+1} (1-n)(2-n)(3-n)\cdots (-2)(-1) \\
&\; \\ %vertical space
& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \cdot \quad 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & \ldots & 1 & \ldots & 1 \\
1 & 2 & \ldots & 2^{j-1} & \ldots & 2^{n-2} \\
1 & 3 & \ldots & 3^{j-1} & \ldots & 3^{n-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & i & \ldots & i^{j-1} & \ldots & i^{n-2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
1  & (n-1) & \ldots & (n-1)^{j-1} & \ldots & (n-1)^{n-2} \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
&\; \\ %vertical space
&= (n-1)! |A_{n-1}|
\end{align*}
By induction on $n$ since $|A_1| = 1$, it follows that
$$
|A_n| = (n-1)!(n-2)!(n-3)!\cdots 2! 1!
$$
as required.

Answer (score 3):

This is a special case of the Vandermonde determinant:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Your determinant is
$$\prod_{1 \le i < j \le n} (j - i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \prod_{j=i+1}^n (j-i) = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} (n-i)! = 1! \dots (n-1)!$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$A_n=
\begin{vmatrix}
1 &1 & \dots &1\\
1 &2 & \dots &2^{n-1}\\
1 &3 & \dots &3^{n-1}\\
& & \dots\\
1 &n & \dots &n^{n-1}\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$ Now Use $$R_k \rightarrow R_k-R_1 \:\forall\,k=2,3,4,\cdots n$$ We get

$$A_n=
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1^2&1^3&\cdots \cdots&1^{n-1}\\
0 &2-1\,\, &2^2-1^2 &2^3-1^3&\cdots \cdots &2^{n-1}-1^{n-1}\\
0 &3-1\,\, &3^2-1^2 &3^3-1^3&\cdots \cdots &3^{n-1}-1^{n-1}\\
0 &4-1\,\, &4^2-1^2 &4^3-1^3&\cdots \cdots &4^{n-1}-1^{n-1}\\
& & \dots\\
0 &n-1\,\, &n^2-1^2 &n^3-1^3&\cdots \cdots &n^{n-1}-1^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}
$$ So
$$A_n=
\begin{vmatrix}
2-1\,\, &2^2-1^2 &2^3-1^3&\cdots \cdots &2^{n-1}-1^{n-1}\\
3-1\,\, &3^2-1^2 &3^3-1^3&\cdots \cdots &3^{n-1}-1^{n-1}\\
4-1\,\, &4^2-1^2 &4^3-1^3&\cdots \cdots &4^{n-1}-1^{n-1}\\
& & \dots\\
n-1\,\, &n^2-1^2 &n^3-1^3&\cdots \cdots &n^{n-1}-1^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}
$$ Since $(a-b)$ is a factor of $a^k-b^k$ we can take $j$ as common factor from $R_j$th row in above Determinant $A_n$ So

$$A_n=(n-1)!
\begin{vmatrix}
1\,\, &3 &2^2+2+1&\cdots \cdots &2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
1\,\, &4 &3^2+3+1&\cdots \cdots &3^{n-2}+3^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
1\,\, &5 &4^2+4+1&\cdots \cdots &4^{n-2}+4^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
& & \dots\\
1\,\, &n+1&n^2+n+1&\cdots \cdots &n^{n-2}+n^{n-3}+\cdots+1
\end{vmatrix}
$$ Now Use $C_2 \rightarrow C_2-2C_1$ $\implies$

$$A_n=(n-1)!
\begin{vmatrix}
1\,\, &1 &2^2+2+1&\cdots \cdots &2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
1\,\, &2 &3^2+3+1&\cdots \cdots &3^{n-2}+3^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
1\,\, &3 &4^2+4+1&\cdots \cdots &4^{n-2}+4^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
& & \dots\\
1\,\, &n-1&n^2+n+1&\cdots \cdots &n^{n-2}+n^{n-3}+\cdots+1
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Now Use $C_3\rightarrow C_3-3C_2-3C_1$ we get
$$A_n=(n-1)!
\begin{vmatrix}
1\,\, &1 &1^2&\cdots \cdots &2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
1\,\, &2 &2^2&\cdots \cdots &3^{n-2}+3^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
1\,\, &3 &3^2&\cdots \cdots &4^{n-2}+4^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
& & \dots\\
1\,\, &n-1&(n-1)^2&\cdots \cdots &n^{n-2}+n^{n-3}+\cdots+1
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Now use $C_4\rightarrow C_4-4C_3-6C_2-4C_1$ we get

$$A_n=(n-1)!
\begin{vmatrix}
1\,\, &1 &1^2& 1^3&\cdots \cdots &2^{n-2}+2^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
1\,\, &2 &2^2&2^3&\cdots \cdots &3^{n-2}+3^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
1\,\, &3 &3^2&3^3&\cdots \cdots &4^{n-2}+4^{n-3}+\cdots+1\\
& & \dots\\
1\,\, &n-1&(n-1)^2&(n-1)^3&\cdots \cdots &n^{n-2}+n^{n-3}+\cdots+1
\end{vmatrix}
$$ In general Continue using

$C_k\rightarrow C_k-\binom{k}{1}C_{k-1}-\binom{k}{2}C_{k-2}-\binom{k}{3}C_{k-3}-\cdots-\binom{k}{k-1}C_1$ Thus we have

$$A_n=(n-1)!A_{n-1}$$ Since $A_1=1$, By Recursion we get

$$A_n=(n-1)!(n-2)!\cdots2!1!$$